# Zurb Foundation 5 Off-canvas menu doesn't work in ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, zurb-foundation, asp.net-core

I have a a Zurb Foundation 5 page with an off-canvas menu.

It all works well when running locally, but when I add it to the *"wwwroot"* in an ASP.NET 6 (vNext) app [and integrate it with Razor] and run it through the web server it doesn't.

To me, it seems like something isn't loading correctly, but no errors visible in the script console.

I run the Beta 2 packages with *KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta2-19561* runtime (from dev feed).

Here's my project: https://github.com/robertsundstrom/aspnet-foundation-template *(/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml)*

Anyone who knows how to solve this?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong on the face of it. Can you do a network trace (using the browser's debug tools) to see whether there are any 404's or anything else while loading the scripts? That is, there might not be any script errors if the scripts themselves can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get an error for something that isn't loading unless you try to call it so I'd make sure that:

- You're running Foundation on that server
- Initialising Foundation on that server
- Running off canvas js or the entire minified foundation js file
- You also need the scss running for off canvas

More here in Foundation docs for what to check on your server where off canvas isn't working: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html